# Symfony2 validation value inside a form event listener?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have the following snippet of code in a Symfony2 form:

```
$builder->add('AccountID');

$builder->get('AccountID')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $Event) {
        //Do something but only if AccountID passed validation
    }
);
```

Right now `POST_SUBMIT` gets triggered whether it passes validation or not.

How can I tell if the field was properly validated inside the event listener?

I'd rather not have an `if` to check for the same validation I specified inside the `validation.yml` on the field.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `$event->getForm()->isValid()`?

This should be reliable if your event listener gets called after the validation step took place.

Note that the validation step is to be found within a form subscriber itself and is listening for `POST_SUBMIT` - same event you are trying to attach to.

For reference, check `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\EventListener\ValidationListener`.

Comment: This looks like it's it. Going to check this out when I'm able to! Thank you

Comment: Whoops, looks like I awarded the bounty prematurely. I thought this worked until I entered an invalid value into the form. The Symfony2 errors show up indicating an invalid value but `$event->getForm()->isValid()` is returning `true` when it shouldn't.

Comment: Got it, looks like `$event->getForm()->isValid()` only works with a listener on the whole form, not on an individual method. So for example `isValid()` works inside `$builder->addEventListener()` but not `$builder->get('AccountID')->addEventListener()`

Comment: And although this is the correct answer, you're not able to add fields with a listener on the whole form. You get the `You cannot add children to a submitted form` exception. So doing a subform listener is the best bet, now I just need to figure out how.

Comment: Have you figured it out? Haven't had StackOverflow open for more than a week now.

Comment: nope, I've moved on from that project and Symfony's form builder can be quite limited. Using Symfony as a REST API and having a separate front end that manages forms in HTML5 natively has been way better.

Answer (score 2):

in symfony 4 i do like this for validating form input base on another form element  :

```
    ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                   $cardData=$event->getData();
                   $form=$event->getForm();

                    if(Your Valdiation Condition){

                        }
                        else{
                      $form->addError(new FormError("form error message"));
                        }
  });
```